# Laravel application on Bitnami(Apache) server turns POST into GET requests

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, apache, bitnami

I'm fairly new to hosting applications & systems myself, and I've just setup a Laravel application on Bitnami with LAMP from AWS. The web parts works well using nova, and the api works great locally using php artisan serve, yet on the server, sending a login request through Postman turns the **POST** request into a **GET** request.

I've tried to figure out different configurations that could cause the issue on the server side but I'm not finding anything relevant, if anyone has any clue I would appreciate any help I can get!

Let me know if you need any parts from the code/config files :)
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

**https-vhost file**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/PROJ_FOLDER/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/PROJ_CERT"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/PROJ_CERT_KEY"
  # BEGIN: Configuration for letsencrypt
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
  # END: Configuration for letsencrypt
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
  </IfModule>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  # BEGIN: Enable non-www to www redirection
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
  # END: Enable non-www to www redirection
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/PROJ_FOLDER/public">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
  <Location /.well-known>
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      ProxyPass !
    </IfModule>
  </Location>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
  </VirtualHost>
```

**bitnami.conf file**

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

# Let Apache know we're behind a SSL reverse proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/PROJ_FOLDER/public"
  # BEGIN: Configuration for letsencrypt
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
  # END: Configuration for letsencrypt
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
  </IfModule>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  # BEGIN: Enable HTTP to HTTPS redirection
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
  # END: Enable HTTP to HTTPS redirection
  # BEGIN: Enable non-www to www redirection
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
  # END: Enable non-www to www redirection
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/PROJ_FOLDER/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
  <Location /.well-known>
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      ProxyPass !
    </IfModule>
  </Location>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
</VirtualHost>

Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf"
```

Access log for the login request

```
IP - DATE "POST /api/v0/users/login HTTP/1.1" 302 226
IP - DATE "GET /api/v0/users/login HTTP/1.1" 301 254
IP - DATE - "GET /api/v0/users/login HTTP/1.1" 405 559951
```

**SOLVED!**
I have no idea how it got solved by through a bunch of tests and tries in the server configurations it worked.

// Exi

Comment: give more details on your host configuration

Comment: @HamidShariati I've edited in some of the config files that I assume matter, as I said I'm new to hosting so let me know if you need anything else! Thanks! :)

Comment: is it localh? and what did you mean "Postman turns the POST request into a GET request."?

Comment: @HamidShariati It's on a EC2 instance on AWS, Bitnami configured. When I send a POST request to login, with a body of username+pw, I get a response from Laravel saying that a GET request is not allowed to the login route. If I check the access logs I see it going in as a POST but getting re-directed to a GET somehow (I'll edit in these logs to the post so you can see what I mean). If I do artisan serve on my Mac (so actually local) the api endpoints work perfectly

Comment: what's your route specification? (middleware and gates)

Comment: @HamidShariati In Laravel this is the only route towards login 
"Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login');", I think there's some middleware to redirect other endpoints that needs authentication but this one does not.

Comment: what's the content of UserController::login ?

Comment: @HamidShariati Okay so I've somehow solved the issue, I redid a bunch of the config files of the server and now it seems to work, thanks for all the help! I'll edit the question so people know it's solved, sadly I don't really have an answer as I did so much.. xD